# SAM CLI executable not found - Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to configure PyCharm in order to run a Lambda Function.

First of all in AWS Toolkit I select the SAM CLI executable, and it goes well:
[image]

Anyway, when I want to add a Lambda run configuration pycharm says: Invalid sam executable: "The system couldn't find the specific route."
[image]

My system PATH variable:
[image]

Someone could help me here please, I really don't know what else to do.

Many thanks!
Xevi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that SAM is not installed on your system or path is not configured in pycharm.
Kindly follow the instructions for installing SAM as per the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html).

Comment: Adding to system path worked for me. Had to restart PyCharm.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, I encountered same problem and solved as following;

I assume that you use mac and write in terminal this;

```
which sam
```

This gives you the path where sam installed.

Then copy this and paste into sam cli executable path like below;

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To help people like me:
`which sam` should give a path to the SAM executable, like:
`/opt/homebrew/bin/sam`

Then in Pycharm, open preferences (⌘,) Tools -> AWS, the the first input field should be 'SAM CLI Executable'.Or Put 'SAM' (uppercase) in the settings search bar.

Answer (score 1):

As of a 2023 edition of the toolkit, I faced a similar issue, with the additional nuance that the `SAM CLI Executable` field in the dialog was disabled when I tried to create a new PyCharm Serverless App project.

I solved it as follows:

- show the AWS Toolkit tool window in an existing, standard PyCharm project. (Of course the toolkit needs to be installed already.)
- click the gear for options, then on the ensuing menu, the wrench for `Show AWS Settings`. Enter the full path to the `sam` executable.
- close the existing project. If you don't do this, it looks like the AWS Settings change may not take effect.
- create a new project. I believe the `SAM CLI Executable` field in the dialog is still disabled! But it should not complain about not being able to find it.

It seems like OP probably made a similar setting change (perhaps via the global PyCharm settings?), so it could just be an issue of closing open projects to get that change to take.

Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the dialog, it seems sort of buggy that the path to `sam` isn't displayed for inspection at project creation time even after you've set it correctly.